# Mysql, select together, not separately

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In mysql I want to display **matched information with values**... But the code I use select information separately and I get a bad result. What I want **is to wrap** the "select" functions together so they both look for specific information in mysql database.

Here's the code I use:

```
$name = explode(',',$name); //splits search
$query = "SELECT * FROM lucky WHERE name LIKE '%" . implode("%' AND name LIKE '%", $name) . "%'";

$sname = explode(',',$sname); //splits search
$query = "SELECT * FROM lucky WHERE sname LIKE '%" . implode("%' AND sname LIKE '%", $sname) . "%'";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);



while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<table id='box'>"; 

 echo "<tr;>";
 echo "<td id='text''>Name:</td><td id='haha'>" . $row['name']. "</td>"; 
echo "<td id='text'>Second Name:</td><td id='haha'>" . $row['sname'] . "</td>";

 echo "</tr;>";
 echo "</table>";


} else { echo "No mathed information" ; }
```

Thanks in advance :)

**UPADATE**

Thanks to Spencer for his help!!!

Here's the code that I use now. Please use this to select matched information from the database!!!

```
$query = SELECT *
  FROM lucky
 WHERE name LIKE '$name'
  AND  sname LIKE '$sname' 

    $result = $mysqli->query($query);



    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "<table id='box'>"; 

     echo "<tr;>";
     echo "<td id='text''>Name:</td><td id='haha'>" . $row['name']. "</td>"; 
    echo "<td id='text'>Second Name:</td><td id='haha'>" . $row['sname'] . "</td>";

     echo "</tr;>";
     echo "</table>";


    } else { echo "No mathed information" ; }
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `$sname` string contains the value "`jack,jill`", then the query would only return rows that have a `name` column value that contains *both* of those strings, for example: `'jack and jill'` and `'jillojellojacko'` would match. But the query will *not* return rows where the `name` column contains `'jack'` but doesn't contain `'jill`'.

If your intent is to search for rows that have *either* of the values matching, for example

```
$name = 'fee,fi,fo'
$sname = 'fum'
```

That is, any rows where `name` column contains either `'fee'`, or `'fi'`, or `'fo'`, or `sname` column  contains `'fum'`, you could use a query of the form:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM lucky t
 WHERE t.name LIKE '%fee%'
    OR t.name LIKE '%fi%'
    OR t.name LIKE '%fo%'
    OR t.sname LIKE '%fum%'
```

If you replace all those `OR`s with `AND`s, then a row will need to satisfy *all* of those predicates to be returned. If you want a combination of `AND` and `OR`, then use parens to specify the order of precedence...